Using hydration with ngModules
When enabling hydration on an older application, which is on ng17, how do you skip hydrating modules?
The Angular docs give the option for how to skip a standalone application and how to skip in the html on a tag. However when you have modules which are loaded through the <router-outlet> How can we skip hydrating?
Have tried adding host: {ngSkipHydration: 'true'} to the component which is throwing an eslint error: @angular-eslint/no-host-metadata-property
The @angular-eslint version is 17.3.0
